Is the Ildatch a metaphor for the Bible?
So once upon a time, Terry Brooks wrote a very favorable introduction to Philip Pullman's His Dark Materials (or more specifically, at least one edition of Northern Lights, but my memory of the exact details is unclear). Like, I wish I had a copy at hand, to see if it could help justify my question further.
Because now much of the Shannara mythos turns on the Ildatch, an evil and living book that background-causes First King and The Sword (of Shannara), directly shows up in Wishsong, and has a graphic novel to its name too (something about a page that escapes the main text's destruction I think).
I don't know that the creation of the Ildatch has any sort of canonical explanation; but then that lack of knowledge is part of my question. A dedicated Shannara wiki says that its origins are in the Age of Faerie, the time of the first Forbidding. If the Ildatch were an elder demon, it would've gone behind the Forbidding at the time. The way that Findo Gask and other such demons show up in Genesis is reminiscent of the emergence of the Shadowen in Heritage, i.e. we are not shown any indication that Gask/Dall used the Ildatch (and Rimmer Dall couldn't have anyway, the whole book was destroyed by then).
Now the Ildatch itself claims to be from the Word. As if to say:

In the beginning there was the Word. And the Ildatch was of the Word, the Ildatch was in the Word. The Ildatch was in the Word in the beginning.

But so now I wonder...
Is the Ildatch a metaphor for the Bible? How much of Brooks' praise of Pullman reflects a concern over dogmatism, is praise of someone fighting against religious dogmatism? I feel like the very last publication-order Shannara books to date include a parable about climate change (or: not even a parable, it's half the main plot point, what with the overseas invaders fleeing climate change in their area!). So Brooks does have that much apparent history of subtle sociopolitical commentary, to his name. (And I've forgotten almost all the Landover saga, so forgive me if I'm omitting reference to some other clear examples of Brooks' philosophy.)

(and the PC game!)

Honestly your evidence leads me more to a Morgoth / satan archetype , in book form, rather than a Bible comparison
